# QML Splash Screen Not Working

Tags: qt, splash-screen, qml

My app used to work before the latest belle update but doesnt anymore. The splash screen only works when i downgrade com.nokia.symbian 1.1 to 1.0 on both the init.qml file and the splashcreen.qml file but then doesnt display the main.qml file. When I instruct main.cpp to directly load main.qml the app does work…. Im lost! Here is the code I have for main.cpp:

```
   #include <QtGui/QApplication>
   #include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"

   Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));

QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationLockPortrait);
viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/SmartFlyer/init.qml"));
//viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qrc:qml/SmartFlyer/main.qml"));
viewer.showExpanded();

return app->exec();
   }
```

For init.qml:

```
   import QtQuick 1.1
   import com.nokia.symbian 1.1

   Item {
       id: init

       SplashScreen {
           id: splash
           show: true              // show splash
           minTimeout: 3000         // show splash at least for 3 sec
    image: "data/splash_screen.png"  // path to splash image
    canFinish: false         // change to true when main QML will be loaded
    z: 100                   // highest page.
}

Loader { // this component performs deferred loading.
    id: mainLoader
    onStatusChanged: {
        if( mainLoader.status == Loader.Ready )
        {
            // main page is loaded
            // time to hide splash
            splash.canFinish = true
        }
    }
}

Component.onCompleted:  {
    // splash is already rendered on the screen
    // user is looking on splash
    // now we can start loader to load main page
    mainLoader.source = "main.qml"
}
   }
```

And for splashscreen.qml :

```
   import QtQuick 1.1
   import com.nokia.symbian 1.1

   Rectangle {
       id: splash

       anchors.fill: parent
       color: "black"

property int minTimeout: 3000  // 3s by default.
property string image;            // path to splash image
property bool show: false       // if show is true then image opacity is 1.0, else 0.0

property bool canFinish: false    // if true then we can hide spash after timeout

state: show ? "showingSplash" : ""

onStateChanged: {
    if( state == "showingSplash" )
        splashTimer.start();
}

opacity: 0.0

Image {
    source: image
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    anchors.fill: parent
    smooth: true
}

Timer {
    id: splashTimer
    interval: minTimeout
    running: false
    repeat:  true
    onTriggered: {
        if( splash.canFinish )
        {
            // finally we can stop timer and hide splash
            splash.show = false
            splashTimer.repeat = false
        }
        else
        {
            // canFinish is false, but main.qml is not loaded yet
            // we should run timer again and again
            splashTimer.interval = 1000 // 1 sec
            splashTimer.repeat = true
        }
    }
}

states: [
    State {
        name: "showingSplash"
        PropertyChanges { target: splash;  opacity: 1.0 }
    }
]

// hide splash using animation
transitions: [
    Transition {
        from: ""; to: "showingSplash"
        reversible: true
        PropertyAnimation { property: "opacity";  duration: 500; }
    }
]
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

As for me, I use an "old school" way to show Splash without any QML. Here you can see, how to construct it, with image logo placed on the gradiented background:

```
QSplashScreen *Application::buildSplashScreen() {
    const QPixmap logoPixmap(":/images/logo.png");
    QDesktopWidget *desktop = QApplication::desktop();
    QRect desktopRect = desktop->availableGeometry();
    QPixmap splashPixmap(desktopRect.width(), desktopRect.height());
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&splashPixmap);
    QLinearGradient backgroundGradient(splashPixmap.rect().width() / 2,
                                       0,
                                       splashPixmap.rect().width() / 2,
                                       splashPixmap.rect().height());
    backgroundGradient.setColorAt(0, QColor::fromRgb(40, 50, 57));
    backgroundGradient.setColorAt(1, QColor::fromRgb(19, 25, 29));
    painter.fillRect(splashPixmap.rect(), backgroundGradient);
    QRect logoRect((splashPixmap.width() - logoPixmap.width()) / 2,
                   (splashPixmap.height() - logoPixmap.height()) / 2,
                   logoPixmap.width(),
                   logoPixmap.height());
    painter.drawPixmap(logoRect, logoPixmap);
    painter.end();
    QScopedPointer<QSplashScreen> splashScreen(new QSplashScreen(splashPixmap));
    if (desktopRect.width() > desktopRect.height()) {
        splashScreen->setAttribute(Qt::WA_LockLandscapeOrientation, true);
    } else {
        splashScreen->setAttribute(Qt::WA_LockPortraitOrientation, true);
    }
    return splashScreen.take();
}
```

Then I use this manually built splash when program starts up:

```
int Application::run() {
    QScopedPointer<QSplashScreen> splashScreen(buildSplashScreen());
    splashScreen->showFullScreen();
    QScopedPointer<QDeclarativeView> applicationWindow(buildRootView());
    splashScreen->finish(applicationWindow.data());
    applicationWindow->showFullScreen();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```