# How to create a splash screen using QML

Tags: qt, qml, splash-screen

I am trying to develop an android application using QT. 
I want to show a splash screen at the start of the application. Splash screen will stay there for 2 seconds then main page of the app will be shown.
For this I have created 2 .qml files.

Splash.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    signal timeout

    Image {
        id: image
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        width: 300
        height: 300
        source: "qrc:/../Desktop/photo_2018-03-21_19-53-06.jpg"
    }

    Text {
        id: text1
        y: image.height + image.y + 20
        text: qsTr("@startimeahmet Presents")
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        font.pixelSize: 25
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 2000; running: true; repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            visible = false
            window.timeout()
        }
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: false
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height

    Splash {
        onTimeout: root.visible = true
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any help on this is appreciated.

p.s. I am using QT 5.11.1 with QT Creator 4.6.2

Comment: a duplicate of [QML Splash screen not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192823/qml-splash-screen-not-working)

Comment: hi, I don't think this is a duplicate question. The one you are referring to is a really old question, and doesn't really help with anything.. @MohammadKanan

Comment: I didn't flag your question as duplicate, while there are other questions similar to yours, just do some search on StakOverFlow.  "_How to load QML file from main.qml_"

Comment: Believe me I did.. But I need someone to look at my code and find out what is wrong. I have spent more than 2 days trying to figure this out. @MohammadKanan

Comment: First you need to use `Loader` to load your `splash.qml` from `main.qml`

Comment: And how could you possibly have a `signal` from splash window? where and how you will receive that signal?

Comment: I have thought about using a `Loader`. Isn't `Loader` for more complicated tasks? I mean what I am trying to do here is to call another .qml file in the beginning of the program.  `Signal` can be exported this way. I have seen several examples of it on the net.

Comment: I guess that you cannot show Window which is child of invisible one.

Comment: With `Loader` you dynamically load qml components, The way you are using `Splash` is not dynamic loading but for _registered_ c++ classes. If you want to load `Splash.qml` then you can only user `Loader`

Comment: @folibis I don't what you mean _Can't show window child of invisible one_ but yes with a `Loader` OP can show timed splash screen while `ApplicationWindow` is invisible

Answer (score 5):

Use a native Android splash screen.

1. Create the splash resource in `android/res/drawable/splash.xml`. Something like

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
>     <item>
>         <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
>             <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
>         </shape>
>     </item>    <item>
>         <bitmap
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:src="@drawable/app"/>
>     </item>
> </layer-list>
> ```

2. Create a theme in `android/res/values/apptheme.xml`:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
>     <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
>         <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
>         <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ffffff</item>
>     </style>
> </resources>
> ```

3. In android/AndroidManifest.xml find the `activity` element and add this attribute: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`
   Add these:

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/splash"/>
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_sticky" android:value="true"/>
   ```
4. In you .pro file add

   QT += androidextras
5. In your C++ code add this line when your app is ready:

   QtAndroid::hideSplashScreen(250);
6. Enjoy!

Comment: Seems like the way to go! `QtAndroid::hideSplashScreen(250);` Does this do a native android call without having to go through `QAndroidJniObject` ?

Comment: Yes, it's a Qt API available in the androidextras module. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroid.html#hideSplashScreen-1

Comment: @FlavioTordini QtAndroid::hideSplashScreen(250); The sentence is not working. I using Qt 5.15.1.

Comment: This works, the only problem is that the transparency fade out animation triggered by the delay passed to hideSplashScreen is not correctly handled. The solid bg and the logo animation are not synced.

Answer (score 3):

As I said since your `ApplicationWindow` is invisible and all its children are invisible too, including your splash window. So `Splash` and `ApplicationWindow` at least should be siblings. But the better solution is to use `Loader` as @Mohammad Kanan already noticed. In this case there is an additional advantage - each window will be initialized at appropriate time and will be unloaded after use. The example:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Loader {
    id: loader
    Component {
        id: splash
        Window {
            id: splashWindow
            signal timeout()
            width: 300
            height: 200
            modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
            flags: Qt.SplashScreen
            color: "#DEDEDE"
            ProgressBar {
                id: progress
                anchors {
                    left: parent.left
                    right: parent.right
                    bottom: parent.bottom
                }
                value: 0
                to : 100
                from : 0
            }
            Timer {
                id: timer
                interval: 50
                running: true
                repeat: true
                onTriggered: {
                    progress.value++;
                    if(progress.value >= 100) {
                        timer.stop();
                        splashWindow.timeout();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: root
        Window {
            id: rootWindow
            width: 800
            height: 600
        }
    }

    sourceComponent: splash
    active: true
    visible: true
    onStatusChanged: {
        if (loader.status === Loader.Ready)
            item.show();
    }

    Connections {
        id: connection
        target: loader.item
        onTimeout: {
            connection.target = null;
            loader.sourceComponent = root;
        }
    }
}
```