# How to display the splash screen immediately when Qt/QML android app is launched?

Tags: android, qt, qml, splash-screen

I have empty **Qt/QML android** app and I am trying to display splash screen.

**Without** Splash screen implementation this screens are displayed:

[image]

Now I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351146/how-to-create-a-splash-screen-using-qml/51381445#51381445) example for splash screen which add the **splash  screen in the android manifest** file. And this is the result I got:

[image]

My question is, Is it possible to avoid **Screen number 1**? Instead of screen 1, I want Splash screen to be displayed immediately when app is launched. Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a solution for this problem thanks to this [post](https://medium.com/@benlaud/complete-guide-to-make-a-splash-screen-for-your-qml-android-application-567ca3bc70af#.8mu6d1eup).

Author of that post, for splash screens in **Qt/QML android** app wrote:

> Basically, you could ignore any solution by C++/QML code only. Because
> they are started late.

I would like to add that, when  author said **"they are started late"**, I think it is because all of your **Qt/QML android app** is compiled at the end like **.so (shared library)**. So when your app start, what happens behind is:

1. Launching the app
2. Loading the **shared library** (your Qt/QML android app)
3. Calling **main()** from your app (shared library)

Now the solution to display splash screen(Steps from the post above):

1. Create template from QtCreator for your android app if you don't have created yet.
2. Create **splash.xml** inside **android/res/drawable**, like [this](https://github.com/benlau/androidnative.pri/blob/master/examples/androidnativeexample/android-sources/res/drawable/splash.xml)
3. Create custom theme, **apptheme.xml** inside **android/res/values**, like [this](https://github.com/benlau/androidnative.pri/blob/master/examples/androidnativeexample/android-sources/res/values/apptheme.xml)
4. Add this line in your **activity tag** in **AndroidManifest.xmnl**

   android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
5. Also this line in **AndroidManifest.xml**, inside **activity tag**:

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/splash"/>
   ```
6. Now the rest is in your **main.qml** file. Set your **Window/ApplicationWindow** element as invisible at beginning(as I saw this will hold the splash screen), use Loader for your first page, and when its loaded, set the Window/ApplicationWIndow visible to true. This is my example:

```
Loader
{
    id: loader
    asynchronous: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    sourceComponent: MainScreen
    {
        width: root.width
        height: root.height

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            root.isReady = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Qt5.15 you can select a  Android native splash screen image in AndroidManifest.xml (in QtCreator)

Other option is to start your software with a simple and fast window: just a window, a image (async), a timer, and a loader for the rest of your software.

When the timer is activated (within 1-2 seconds), you can start the loader.

Comment: thank you for answering.  I have used template for splash screen from QtCreator but that didn't help. 
 About other option, "to start your software...",  as I understand you, in my main.qml I need simple Image which will be my splash screen and it will be loaded immediatelly and other "part from my main qml" to be placed in Loader{} component which will be loaded later (with using Timer). Am I right?

Comment: yes, you are true. The Idea is to start as soon as possible the splash screen UI, and then, using a 150ms timer & loader, do a dynamic load of the real UI